# Разместить 2 формы на одной странице

Tags: php, html, form

Как можно разместить 2 формы на одной странице так, чтобы если работаю с одной формой и жму `submit`, то вторая бы форма не очищалась до нажатия кнопки на ней? Конкретней так, в первой форме человек ведет запись, а вторая служит для подгрузки информации на сервер(не спрашивайте зачем, так надо, чтобы было отдельно). И допустим, если он написал текст в 1 форме, а потом работает со второй и нажимает там кнопку, то очищаются обе формы. Как можно этого избежать? Чтобы текст в 1 форме остался до того момента, пока человек не нажмет кнопку.

```php
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="Заголовок" style="width: 374px;"><br>
    <button type="submit">Отправить данные</button>
</form>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="news" placeholder="Заголовок" style="width: 374px;"><br>
    <button type="submit">Отправить данные</button>
</form>
<?php
$state = $_POST["state"];
$news = $_POST["news"];
if(isset($state)){
    echo $state;
}
if(isset($news)){
    echo $news;
}
?>
```

Comment: Никак, по сути это даже неправильная логика. Но если так уж надо, помещайте значения с обеих форм, например, в localStorage или куки

Answer (score 2):

используйте для каждой формы отправку данных по AJAX, т.е. вы будете работать без перезагрузки страницы. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635563/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-ajax?rq=1) есть пример для одной формы.

Comment: Поддерживаю, очень полезно.